# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'empstatus'

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner in Laravel 7, I am using two tables 'empmast' and 'empatten'. I displayed the values of empmast (empid, empname) and joined two fields (empstatus, doa) with same. Then I tried to push these values to 'empatten' table. The thing is these values are trying to save in the empmast instaed empatten table. Kindly assist.

Complete Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'empstatus' in 'field list'  
(SQL: insert into `empmast` (`empid`, `empname`, `empstatus`, `doa`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, Kirupa Shankar, Present, 17-05-2020, 2020-05-17 06:34:26, 2020-05-17 06:34:26))
```

**EmpAttenController**:

```
use App\Empatten;
use App\Empmast;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EmpAttenController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, Empatten $empatten)
    {
        $member1 = $request->input('empid');
        $member2 = $request->input('empname');
        $member3 = $request->input('empstatus');
        $member4 = $request->input('doa');


        for ($i = 0; $i < count($member1); $i++) {

            $empatten->empid = $member1[$i];
            $empatten->empname = $member2[$i];
            $empatten->empstatus = $member3[$i];
            $empatten->doa = $member4;
            $empatten->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**Empatten**(Model):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Empatten extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'empid'     => 'array',
        'empname'   => 'array',
        'empstatus' => 'array',
        'doa'
    ];
}
```

Comment: I am receiving the values of the empmast tables and additionally adding two fields empstatus & doa. The empatten tables has these fields, empid, empname, empstatus, doa

Comment: The error, however, is saying that `empstatus` doesn't exist on the `empmast` table which makes me think that either the code you've provide isn't causing the error or you haven't provided all of the related code. Also, Just out of curiosity, what are you trying to achieve with the `for` loop in your `store()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Create new instance of your model before you try to save

```
    use App\Empatten;
    use App\Empmast;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class EmpAttenController extends Controller
    {
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $member1 = $request->input('empid');
            $member2 = $request->input('empname');
            $member3 = $request->input('empstatus');
            $member4 = $request->input('doa');


            for ($i = 0; $i < count($member1); $i++) {
                $empatten = new Empatten(); // initiate your model class
                $empatten->empid = $member1[$i];
                $empatten->empname = $member2[$i];
                $empatten->empstatus = $member3[$i];
                $empatten->doa = $member4;
                $empatten->save();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got this working, by adding a piece of code protected $table = 'empatten';under model